addLocatorHandler: iFrame cannot be found
I am currently trying to implement the addLocatorHandler from Playwright. However, with my current code, the iFrame is never found. Example code:
@BeforeClass
    public void locatorHandlerTest() {
        getPage().addLocatorHandler(getPage().frameLocator("//iframe[contains(@id, 'offer')]").owner(), overlay -> {
            overlay.locator("//span[contains(text(), 'Close')]").click();
            }, new Page.AddLocatorHandlerOptions().setTimes(3));
    }

The iFrame that I am looking for looks like this:
<iframe id="offer_ea2b1925a740598be667-0" name="offer_ea2b1925a740598be667-0" title="offer_ea2b1925a740598be667-0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" allow="payment" allowfullscreen="true" src="https://buy-eu.piano.io/checkout/template/cacheableShow?aid=LbGa28Pope&amp;templateId=OTS8XB3CJ94D&amp;offerId=fakeOfferId&amp;experienceId=EX2VALKHILLA&amp;iframeId=offer_ea2b1925a740598be667-0&amp;displayMode=modal&amp;pianoIdUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fid-eu.piano.io%2Fid%2F&amp;widget=template&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dewezet.de" frameborder="0" class="" style="overflow: hidden; background-color: transparent; border: 0px; width: 735px; height: 714px;"></iframe>

The aim is to close overlays that appear randomly. Thank you very much and I would appreciate any help.

Have you verified that the iframe is not found and that it's not the elements inside the iframe? If the iframe hasn't loaded then yet, you could try overlay.waitFor() ?

Try to strip the code apart, you are doing several things at the same time and it may be that the locator is working.
I understand that you want to grab the iframe and then look into it for the DOM text 'Close'?
Do you get a NullPointerException or something to help pinpoint it?

Yes, you're right. The overlay is an iFrame and I want to click on “Close” in the overlay. If I have the code in the @BeforeClass class (TestNG), then no exception occurs because the overlay has not yet appeared.
Others have recommended using “waitFor()”, which usually results in an exception because the overlay does not appear in time either.
The problem is probably due to the fact that the entire test takes several hours.

Too complicated to solve here I guess... specially with the hours restriction xd
